# I'm having trouble finding the sum of this infinite series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble on finding the sum of:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{9^n}
$$

I tried solving this as if it were a geometric series where I would write $1/(1-x)$ where $x=-\frac19$ but that didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you that did not work?

Comment: Hint: the first term is $\dfrac 19$ not $1$

Comment: @Mehdi I thought the sum would be in the form of 1/(1-x) where (-1/9) would be the x. So it would come out to 1/(1-(-1/9))

Comment: @JMartinez, you are thinking of geometric series, $a(1+r+...)$, starting at $a=1$. Here, $a = 1/9$ and $r= -1/9$. The easiest way is to write the sum as $\frac{a}{1-r}$. Why?

Comment: Yea I just saw where I was wrong and instead of 1/(1-(-1/9)) I put (1/9)/(1-(-1/9)) and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{9^n} = -\left(\dfrac{-1}{9}\right)^n$